# class hierarchy of Notation3

Tags: class, sparql, dotnetrdf, n3

i have a simple notation3 ontology

```
@prefix my: <http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/n3_notation#>.
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .



    my:spec a rdfs:Class.
    my:security a rdfs:Class; rdfs:subClassOf my:spec .

    my:bluetooth a my:security;
    my:preferedby my:BusinessPerson;
    my:name "bluetooth".
```

im trying to define class `spec`and define `security` class as a subclass of `spec`.

this is my sparql query im using with the help of dotNetRdf library

```
PREFIX my: <http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/n3_notation#>
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
    [ a my:spec;
        my:preferedby my:BusinessPerson;
        my:name ?name].
}";
```

according to class hierarchy this query should return 'bluetooth' as an answer since `security` is a subclass of `spec` (according to my knowledge) . but so far no result. can some one help me with this where i have done my mistake ? thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2):

> im trying to define class specand define security class as a subclass of spec.

I think you've done this part correctly.

> according to class hierarchy this query should return 'bluetooth' as an answer since security is a subclass of spec (according to my knowledge) .

To infer that the instance which is asserted to be of type **security** is also an instance of type **spec**, you need at least RDFS inferencing.  SPARQL doesn't provide that directly, though many endpoints and triple stores may have some support for it.    However, some basic forms of inference *can* be encoded with SPARQL, and you can get your query to work in this case.  You just need to adjust your query (and add the **rdfs:** prefix) to this:

```sql
SELECT ?name WHERE {
    [ a rdfs:subClassOf*/my:spec;
        my:preferedby my:BusinessPerson;
        my:name ?name].
}
```

This literally says that you want to find an instance of a class C where C is connected by a chain of **rdfs:subClassOf** links of length zero or more to **my:spec**.  In this case, that means everything that's either a **security** or a **spec**.

For more about doing RDFS and OWL inferencing in SPARQL, you may find some of these questions and answers helpful:

- [Using SPARQL for limited RDFS and OWL reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20474862/1281433)
- [Sparql query Subclass or EquivalentTo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21092246/1281433)
- [how to do reasoning in Jena via Sparql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24136532/1281433)

Comment: The first triple pattern looks odd, so I guess there was some problem with the formatting?

Comment: @Joshua Taylor I changed my query according to your instructions        it shows the error  'VDS.RDF.Parsing.Tokens.MultiplyToken' Token which is valid only after a Predicate to indicate Path Cardinality

Comment: @Joshua Taylor should i change rdfs: name space to my and have only my: name space ?